# How do i add items to ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview, textbox

I have a listview in my TimePage xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="moduleList" Width="1120" Height="231" Margin="42,536,186,217" Grid.Column="1" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Program Name" Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Program Code" Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding code}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Number of Credits" Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding credits}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Number of Hours" Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding hours}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Semester start date" Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding date}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Semester Weeks" Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding weeks}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Study Hours" Width="160" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding studyhours}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

my values are being taken from myModule class and each variable is binded to a variable:

```
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string code { get; set; }
     public int credits { get; set; }
     public int hours { get; set; }
     public string date { get; set; }
     public int studyhours { get; set; }
     public int weeks { get; set; }
```

I make use of this code in the TimePage.cs in order to allow me to add values into listView:

```
 List<Modules> modules = new List<Modules>();
        modules.Add(new Modules()
        {     
        name =  namebox.Text,
        code =  codebox.Text,
        credits = int.Parse(0+creditbox.Text),
        hours = int.Parse(0+hoursbox.Text),
        date = semesterbox.Text,
        weeks = int.Parse(0+semesterweekbox.Text),
        studyhours = m1.Calculations(int.Parse(hoursbox.Text),
                   int.Parse(creditbox.Text),
                   int.Parse(semesterweekbox.Text)),


    }) ;
```

The code works and it allows me to output values onto the list box it comes out like this:
[image: ListView Output]

However, when I try to input new values it does not output a new item rather it updates the information on the first item:

[image: ListView new values]

how do I make it add a new item instead of updating information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create readonly field with an observable collection:

```cs
private readonly ObsrvableCollection<Modules> modules
    = new ObservableCollection<Modules>();
```

Once, after initializing the XAML, assign the field value to the ListView source:

```cs
    InitializeComponent();
    moduleList.ItemsSource = modules;
```

After that, in the code, work only with the collection in the field.
Leave the ListView UI alone.

```cs
   modules.Add(new Modules()
        {     
            name =  namebox.Text,
            code =  codebox.Text,
            credits = int.Parse(0+creditbox.Text),
            hours = int.Parse(0+hoursbox.Text),
            date = semesterbox.Text,
            weeks = int.Parse(0+semesterweekbox.Text),
            studyhours = m1.Calculations
                (
                   int.Parse(hoursbox.Text),
                   int.Parse(creditbox.Text),
                   int.Parse(semesterweekbox.Text)
                )
        }
   );
```

Comment: Do I create the read-only field in the TimePage.cs ?

Comment: You must create such a field in the file where you currently have the code `List <Modules> modules = new List <Modules> ();`
Most likely you have it in the "TimePage.xaml.cs" file.
For a more accurate answer, show the full contents of the file from which you showed this line of code.